# Why the sum of the digits of $9k+a$ (where $k,a\in \mathbb{N}$, and $0<a<8$) is equal to $9l+a$ (where $\mathbb{N}\ni l< k$)?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, integers

The sum of the digits of integers that are multiples of $9$ (let's name them $9k$) always add up to another multiple of $9$ (let's call it $9l$). However, I have observed that the sum of the digits of such multiples plus another integer (let's call it $a$, smaller than $9$ in order not to reach the next multiple) add up to another smaller multiple of $9$, $9l$, plus that added integer $a$.

I see this is obvious when the addition only changes one digit (e.g. $5463+6=546\mathbf{9}$, where the sums of the digits of each number equals the sum of the digits of the whole sum; in this case the sum operation has changed the count from $5+4+6+3=18=9\cdot 2=9l$ to $5+4+6+\mathbf{9}=18+6=9\cdot 2 + 6=9l+a$, however I am not seeing it as clearly when more digits are changed (e.g. $5463+7=54\mathbf{70}$; in this case the sum operation has changed the count from $5+4+6+3=18=9\cdot 2=9l_1$ to $5+4+\mathbf{7}+\mathbf{0}=9\cdot 1 +7=9l_0+a$, where it happens $l_0=1<l_1=2$).

Comment: What you're saying is essentially $S(a) = a \pmod{9}$. Assuming you are familiar with the notation, do you see why that could be true?

Comment: I am in fact trying to understand the congruence expression for the "digital root" of a number, that involves that operation. I am not fully sure in detail how the count is performed from each multiple of 9 on, up to the next one (except in the case I've mentioned where only one digit is changed, which is indeed obvious). I've added some more details and it's the last statement between brackets what seems still obscure to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to do it backward:

Let the digits of the number be, in order from right to left, $a_0, a_1, .... a_n$.

So  $a_n + a_{n-1} + ..... + a_1 + a_0 = 9l + a$.

$a_n + a_{n-1} + ....... + 9a_1 + a_1 + a_0 = 9l + 9a_1 + a$

$a_n + a_{n-1} + ...... + 10a_1 + a_0 = 9(l + a_1) + a$

$a_n + a_{n-1} + .......99a_2 + a_2 + 10a_1 + a_0 = 9(l+a_1) +99a_2 + a$

$a_n + a_{n-1} + ..... 100a_2 +10a_1 + a_0 = 9(l+a_1 + 11a_2) + a$

.... and so one

$10^na_n + 10^{n-1} + .....  100a_2 + 10a_1 + a_0 = 9(l+a_1 + 11a_2 + .....+1111...1a_{n-1} + 1111...11a_n) + a$.

But  $10^na_n + 10^{n-1} + .....  100a_2 + 10a_1 + a_0$ is our original number!

So $9k +a = 9l + a$ and $k = (l+a_1 + 11a_2 + .....+1111...1a_{n-1} + 1111...11a_n)$

Comment: Thank you, this was more explicit and simple for me since I'm not very familiar with modular arithmetic. There's a typo at the end since $9k+a$ can obviously not be just equal to $9l+a$ (unless it were the zero number), and I think it should be $9k+a>9l+a$ instead.

Answer (score 2):

Fact: $ 10^ i \equiv 1 \pmod{9} $.  (Do you see why?)

So, if $ n = \overline{n_k n_{k-1} \ldots n_2 n_1 n_0}$, then
$$\sum_{i=0}^k n_i \times 10^i \equiv \sum_{i=0}^k n_i \times 1 \pmod{9}. $$

Hence, if $ n = 9k + a$, then $ \sum n_i  = 9l + a $.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I understand the first line; I cannot see however what the overbar notation on the second line, and the quantities $a_j$ are. But essentially I believe it's just a proof the digits of a multiple of $9$ add up to another multiple of 9 right? I already knew that, and sorry in advance maybe I am missing something very trivial but still cannot understand clearly the last step in the last line... The digits of "a multiple of $9$" add up to "another multiple of $9$"; but why the digits of "a multiple of $9$ plus $a$" always add up to "another multiple of $9$ plus $a$"?

Comment: 1) I switched notation, so now $n_i$ are the digits of the number $n$. The overbear notation means "read this as concatenated digits, as opposed to multiplying them. 2) Let $n $ be "a multiple of 9 plus a". The centralized equation says "Taken modulo 9, the number $n$ is equivalent to the sum of the digits of $n$". What this means is that if  "$n$ is a multiple of 9 , plus $a$", then "the sum of the digits of $n$, is a multiple of 9, plus $a$".